# Getting context help in Cursive IDE?

Tags: clojure, cursive

How can I get Context Help in Cursive IDE?

```
(map inc [1 2 3 4])
 ^^^
```

when my cursor is over "map" I want to see document for "map"?

Answer (score 0):

View > Quick Documentation or 
View > External Documentation

works